# Why aren't the events that a natural number is divisible by $3$ and that a natural number is divisible by $5$ in the interval $[1, 50]$ independent?

Tags: probability

We select a number $n$ out of the first $50$ natural numbers - 50 outcomes

$P(\text{$n$ is divisible by $5$}) = 10/50$

$P(\text{$n$ is divisible by $3$}) = 16/50$

$P(\text{$n$ is divisible by both $5$ and $3$}) = 3/50$ since there are only $3$ such numbers, $15, 30, 45$

Why isn't $P(\text{$5$ and $3$}) = P(5) \cdot P(3)$?

As far as I can tell, they are independent events, a number can be divisible by $3$ whether or not it is divisible by $5$ and vice versa, so why doesn't the formula apply?

Comment: AS you have shown… the events are not independent. What makes you think so? You proved your intuition wrong so don't believe in it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you obtained $16$ multiples of $3$ among the first $50$ natural numbers, I will assume you are defining the natural numbers to be the positive integers rather than the nonnegative integers (there is not universal agreement on the definition of natural numbers).

The number of natural numbers divisible by $k$ in the interval $[1, m]$ is
$$\left\lfloor \frac{m}{k} \right\rfloor$$
where the floor function $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor$ yields the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.  Notice the dependence of the answer on $m$.  In general, whether the event that a number $n$ in the interval $[1, m]$ is divisible by $3$ and the event that a number $n$ in the interval $[1, m]$ is divisible by $5$ depends on $m$ since the number of multiples of $3$, $5$, and $15$ in the interval $[1, m]$ all depend on $m$.

The number $50$ is divisible by $5$ but not by $3$.  As you showed, the probability that a natural number $n$ in the interval $[1, 50]$ is divisible by $3$ and the probability that a natural number $n$ in the interval $[1, 50]$ is divisible by $5$ are not independent events since
$$\Pr(\text{$n$ is divisible by $3$} \cap \text{$n$ is divisible by $5$}) \neq \Pr(\text{$n$ is divisible by $3$})\Pr(\text{$n$ divisible by $5$})$$
Consider the same problem for the interval $[1, 75]$.  Notice that $75$ is divisible by both $3$ and $5$, so it is also divisible by $15$.
\begin{align*}
\left\lfloor \frac{75}{3} \right\rfloor & = \left\lfloor 25 \right\rfloor = 25\\
\left\lfloor \frac{75}{5} \right\rfloor & = \left\lfloor 15 \right\rfloor = 15\\
\left\lfloor \frac{75}{15} \right\rfloor & = \left\lfloor 5 \right\rfloor = 5  
\end{align*}
Therefore, for a natural number $n$ in the interval $[1, 75]$,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{$n$ is divisible by $3$}) = \frac{25}{75} = \frac{1}{3}\\
\Pr(\text{$n$ is divisible by $5$}) = \frac{15}{75} = \frac{1}{5}\\
\Pr(\text{$n$ is divisible by $15$}) = \frac{5}{75} = \frac{1}{15}
\end{align*}
Since
$$\Pr(\text{$n$ is divisible by $3$} \cap \text{$n$ is divisible by $5$}) = \Pr(\text{$n$ is divisible by $3$})\Pr(\text{$n$ is divisible by $5$})$$
the events $n$ is divisible by $3$ and $n$ is divisible by $5$ are independent events in the interval $[1, 75]$.

Comment: But the question is why aren't they independent? the divisibility by 3 is not influenced by the divisibility by 5. It is divisible by 3 whether or not divisible by 5 and vice versa, which shows that they are independent events.

Comment: The real answer has something to do with the fact that the interval should terminate at a multiple of both 3 and 5 e.g. for interval [1..49] P(3) = 16/49, P(5) = 9/49, P(3 and 5) = 3/49, but I cant explain why that influences independence of events

Comment: @user1648764 The problem here is (as mentioned above) YOUR understanding of "independence". In stochastics it doesn't mean "is not influenced", but in your understanding it seems so. So: correct your understanding instead of trying to find a non existing reasoning .

Comment: As I said, the number of multiples of a number in the interval $[1, m]$ depends on $m$.  When $m$ is a multiple of both $3$ and $5$, the event that $n \in [1, m]$ is divisible by $3$ and the event that $n \in [1, m]$ is divisible by $5$ are independent events.  However, that is not true in general for other values of $m$ since the value of $m$ determines how many multiples of $3$ and how many multiples of $5$ exist in the interval $[1, m]$.  Remember that two events $E$ and $F$ are *independent* if $\Pr(E \cap F) = \Pr(E)\Pr(F)$.  If that equation does not hold, they are dependent.